# How to remove this from bed frame corner

Tags: bedroom

How do I remove these bolts from corner of bedframe?

[image]

Comment: Either you'd access them from the other side or they've been mangled beyond recognition. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Is there anything on the end of the bed to the left of the picture?  It could be bolts [like these](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/bed-hardware/connectors/40445-bed-bolts?item=05G1701).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.